# How handle looping an array in PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops

I have an array. I want to check whether an variable (string) contain in that array.
I tried this, but it only check the first array and do the judgment.
And I can not contiue go to the "NEXTFUNCTION" once the array is true, it terminated.

```
function NEXTFUNCTION
{
  ##some process##
}
     $BCUControllerString = @("Configure Storage Controller for Optane","Configure Storage Controller for Raid")
 $DiskInfo = Get-PhysicalDisk | Select-Object FriendlyName, Size | 
 Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -like "*INTEL OPTANE*" -or $_.FriendlyName -like "*INTEL MEM*" -or 
 $_.FriendlyName -like "*INTEL HBRPEK*"}

 if ($DiskInfo)
 {
      #Write-Host "Controller Optane"
      foreach ($ControllerStringOptane in $BCUControllerString)
      {
           if ($ControllerStringOptane -like "*Optane*")
           {
                Write-Host "Controller: $ControllerStringOptane"
                NEXTFUNCTION

           }
           else
           {
                Write-Host "Fail! "
           }    
      }
 }
 else
 {
      Write-Host "Controller Raid"
      foreach ($ControllerStringRAID in $BCUControllerString)
      {
           if ($ControllerStringRAID -like "*Raid*")
           {
                Write-Host "Controller: $ControllerStringRAID"
               NEXTFUNCTION

           }
           else
           {    
                Write-Host "Fail! "
           }
      }
 }
```

Anyone can give idea please. Thank you.

Comment: You have a break that exits the loop once it finds the first matc., apparently the first element is true and it breaks out of the loop. Are you suppose to check DiskInfo in the if statement perhaps?

Comment: In the code snippet you've provided above `elseif (!($DiskInfo))` is unnecessary and is the same as just using `else`. And, it seems you want to execute the 2nd array element only when `$DiskInfo` is `null`. You may want to revisit this logic.

Answer (score 0):

@SBR,
Unless you have more elements to the `$BCUControllerString` array, you can ignore the array altogether and the code gets condensed as shown below.

```
function NEXTFUNCTION
{
  ##some process##
}

$DiskInfo = Get-PhysicalDisk | 
    ? {$_.FriendlyName -like "*INTEL OPTANE*" -or $_.FriendlyName -like "*INTEL MEM*" -or $_.FriendlyName -like "*INTEL HBRPEK*"} | 
    select FriendlyName, Size

if ($DiskInfo)
{
    Write-Host "Controller Optane"
    Write-Host "Controller: Configure Storage Controller for Optane"          
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Controller Raid"
    Write-Host "Controller: Configure Storage Controller for RAID"
}

NEXTFUNCTION
```

**PS:** I've replaced `Where-Object` with its alias `?` and the `Select-Object`'s counterpart `select`